# How to check if the user's first and last names are in the password?

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I'm validating a password following these criteria:
1•Letters and Numbers
2•Allow ‘!’, ‘?’, ‘.’
3•Min 1 capital letter
4•Min 8 chars
5•Max 16 chars
6•Min 2 numbers
7•Does not contain first name
8•Does not contain last name

This code works well for the first 6 conditions, still not able to validate 7 and 8.

```
function validatePassword(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

var allowedInput = new RegExp("^(?=(.*\\d){2})(?=.*[A-Z])[a- 
    zA-Z0-9!?.]{8,16}$");
for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
     if(inputs[i].type == "password"){
          if(inputs[i].value.match(allowedInput)){
               console.log("Pass Good");                        
          }

          else{
           console.log("Only numbers, letters!,?,. allowed\n" + 
                "Between 8 - 16 chars\n" + 
            "Minimum one uppercase letter\n" +
            "Minimum 2 digits\n");                  
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not tag with regex here is another way:

```
var fnlc = firstname.toLowerCase();
var lnlc = lastname.toLowerCase();
var vallc = inputs[i].value.toLowerCase();
var hasname = (vallc.indexOf(fnlc) >= 0 || vallc.indexOf(fnlc) >= 0);
```

If you have your heart set on a regex because you love it so much ;), then just test the names separately:

```
var testNames = new RegExp(firstname+'|'+lastname, "gi");
var hasname = testNames.test(inputs[i].value); // true if found
```

Comment: Thank you, using the guys answers; I could come up with this code:

Comment: if( inputsTolc.includes(firstName) || inputsTolc.includes(lastName)){
     console.log("Wrong first or last names are in password");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code to validate the first name and last name with regular Expression using Javascript

test() – This function is used to perform a regular expression match in JavaScript.

```
var regName = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/;
var name = document.getElementById('nameInput').value;
if(!regName.test(name)){
    alert('Invalid name given.');
}else{
    alert('Valid name given.');
}
```

```
<script>
function validate(){
    var regName = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if(!regName.test(name)){
        alert('Please enter your full name (first & last name).');
        document.getElementById('name').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        alert('Valid name given.');
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For valdation 7 and 8, you can use the `Array.prototype.includes()` and modify your code as shown below:

*I'm assuming **firstName** and the **lastName** to be the variables you can get it from DOM using one of the **Document.querySelector()** or any other DOM manipulator.*

```
function validatePassword(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var allowedInput = new RegExp("^(?=(.*\\d){2})(?=.*[A-Z])[a- 
    zA-Z0-9!?.]{8,16}$");
for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
     if(inputs[i].type == "password" && inputs[i].includes(firstName) && inputs[i].includes(lastName)){
          if(inputs[i].value.match(allowedInput) && ){
               console.log("Pass Good");                        
          }

          else{
           console.log("Only numbers, letters!,?,. allowed\n" + 
                "Between 8 - 16 chars\n" + 
            "Minimum one uppercase letter\n" +
            "Minimum 2 digits\n");                  
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful, by using your code, I could come up with this code:

Comment: if( inputsTolc.includes(firstName) || inputsTolc.includes(lastName)){
     console.log("Wrong first or last names are in password");
    }